# can't convert complex to float in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

here is a part of my code:

```
import math
import numpy as np

M_Matrix = []
for i in range(0, layer + 1):
    # creat phase retardation tilda matrix
    M = [[math.exp(-1j * phase_retardation_tilda[i]), 0],
         [0, math.exp(1j * phase_retardation_tilda[i])]]
    N = (1 / (2 * n_tilda[i+1] * a_mn[i])) * [[n_tilda[i+1] + n_tilda[i], n_tilda[i+1] - n_tilda[i]],
                                              [n_tilda[i+1] - n_tilda[i], n_tilda[i+1] + n_tilda[i]]]
    matrix = np.dot(M, N)
    M_Matrix.append(matrix)
```

I receive this error:

```
   M = [[math.exp(-1j * phase_retardation_tilda[i]), 0],
   TypeError: can't convert complex to float
```

what should i do with this?

Comment: I would advise using numpy instead of math if you're doing complex math.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html): The `math` module cannot be used with complex numbers; use the functions of the same name from the [cmath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#module-cmath) module if you require support for complex numbers. You can use `cmath.exp()` instead of `math.exp()` in your case.

Comment: so thanks, it's worked.